# How to use part of composite key in JPA repository methods to fetch data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I have a class Application with EmbeddedId and second column in embbbedID is forgein key and having many to one relationship with offer.

```
@Entity
   public class Application implements Serializable{

private Integer id;

@EmbeddedId
private MyKey mykey;

private String resume;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private ApplicationStatus applicationStatus;

    @Embeddable
public class MyKey implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotNull
    private String emailId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    private Offer offer;
```

in Offer class mapping is done on jobTitle.

```
 @Repository
interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository <Application,MyKey>
```

{

```
List<Application> findAllByMyKey_Offer(String jobTitle);
}
```

Trying this but getting no success...
I want to fetch All application regarding a specific jobTitle.
What shud be my method name in ApplicationRepository class.

Answer (score 2):

Your methode name is wrong, the right one is `findAllByMykey_Offer` or `findAllByMykeyOffer`, as your field is named mykey.

As mentionned in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ using `List<Application> findAllByMykey_Offer(String jobTitle);` is better than `List<Application> findAllByMykeyOffer(String jobTitle);`

Comment: Thanks for the response.,that worked. what shud be my method name if if i want to fetch only all emailIds for a corresponding jobTitle.

Answer (score 1):

With composite key, your field name should include name of the field of embedded id. In you case it would be like this (I haven't tested it)

```
List<Application> findAllByMykeyOffer(String jobTitle);
```

Notice that `k` is lower-case here, because your field in class `Application` is named `mykey`, not `myKey`

Comment: Thanks for the response.,that worked. what shud be my method name if if i want to fetch only all emailIds for a corresponding jobTitle.